# Tangent Line at given point. Help!

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line at the given point.
$7y^2 − xy^2 − x^3 =0$ the point is $(\frac72,\frac72)$

Ive found the derivative:
$14y\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2-2yx\frac{dy}{dx}-3x^2=0$

Comment: I found the derivative and then plugged in the points to find the slope. I don't know if that is right.

Comment: Can you write this out in your question? It's much easier for people to help you if they know exactly where you need help!

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks!

Comment: The derivative looks right to me! Do you know what to do next?

Comment: No idea.. Thats my problem

Comment: So you have a point on the line and the slope.  Shouldn't you be able to get an equation out of that?

Comment: Kelsey: I recommend you to use \cfrac{dy}{dx} or \dfrac{dy}{dx} instead of \frac{dy}{dx}. $$\cfrac{dy}{dx} $$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ $$\text{Notice the difference.}$$

Comment: That was my correction! Sorry. But thanks for that!

Comment: okay thanks and I guess but what about the dy/dx

Answer (score 3):

I'll start you off: the gradient of the tangent line is given by the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at that point.

1) Sub in the values for $x$ and $y$ and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get the gradient.

2) Once you have the gradient $m$, you need to find the $y$-intercept. Let me know if you need a hint for that.

Comment: couldn't i just write it as y-7/2=m(x-7/2)

Comment: Exactly! So all you need to do is find m. Is that clearer now?

Comment: I got m=2 does that look correct

Comment: $m =2$ is spot on.... sounds like you didn't need that much help!

Comment: Thanks haha! I was plugging in the wrong number and I was just getting super frustrated and then you helped..